# antd - Validate Form when unmount component

Tags: reactjs, antd

Is there any way to validate antd form in return of useEffect/useLayoutEffect?

I tried this but if validation has error, it won't go in catch block and the try block done to the end:

```
useLayoutEffect(()=>{
   const validate = async ()=>{
      try{
        const fields = await form.validateFields();
      }
      catch(err){
         console.error(err);
         //if there is any validation error, this block will not run.
      }
   }
   return () => {
      validate();
   };
})
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code of the "validateFields" function? Is it throwing an error when the form is invalid?
Also what's your motivation to go with useLayoutEffect?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why you did call validate on cleanup function of useEffect? you validated form when it becomes unmount and the validate runs asynchronously and you don't know when it was affect the component and actually validate it.

If you want to catch error on validate you must use catch of validate promise, if it does not work try figure out the form values in useLayoutEffect to see what is the values or it has any values or not

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    form.validateFields()
      .then((values) => {})
      .catch(() => {
        /* do someething base on error info
          errorInfo:
            {
              values: {

              },
              errorFields: [
                { name: [''], errors: [''] },
              ],
              outOfDate: false,
            }
      */
      });
});
```

Comment: Yes, there's no way to run async function in unmounting.
I want to save fields errors and value in context and not save them on each onChange and prevent extra rerendering. I submit form with submit button out of component.

Maybe i use useRef and update it on onChanges and just update context with ref in cleanup.

Comment: if you put more code in your question I can help you better, but you right you can use ref to prevent extra render if you don't want those renders actually